# Using TileBrush in WinRT

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

Apparently, we now have a [TileBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.tilebrush) in WinRT; however, I can't figure out how to use it.  I can't find any property to set the content of the brush.

The Blend beta looks like it has the ability to set a TileBrush on an element, but Blend likes to fall over every time I try to use that to see how it does it. (And it looks more like a mislabeled ImageBrush, anyway.)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's just a base class for ImageBrush - possibly it is there mostly for backwards compatibility...

You would probably need to paint the tiles yourself to a bitmap if you want to have repeated copies of an image as your brush.